# OpenCV VideoCapture failed to open a file, how to determine reason?

Tags: opencv, error-handling

Using C++ OpenCV I was just trying to open a video file in Cygwin environment. For some reason file is not getting opened i.e. isOpened() is always false.

- I checked for "ffmpeg -codecs" output within cygwin and it displays all available video codecs.
- Video exists in the directory and I verified physically

Still unable to open the video file. To debug this issue can I see the error number that get set when videocapture fails to open the file.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    //Tried with both namedWindow and without namedWindow command
    //cv::namedWindow( "Video", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    cv::VideoCapture capture( argv[1], cv::CAP_FFMPEG  );
    if (!capture.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open the file " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        **std::cout << "Reason for catpure fails is  " << ???????**
        exit(0);
    }
    std::cout << "Opened " << argv[1] << std::endl;
    capture.release();
}
```

Note : I have not installed ffmpeg in cygwin environment. Instead I have ffmpeg in my Windows 10 and I had included the same in my Windows PATH environment. Within cygwin I am able to execute ffmpeg command

```
    General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.1 =====================================
      Version control:               unknown
    
      Platform:
        Timestamp:                   2021-01-19T11:33:15Z
        Host:                        CYGWIN 3.1.7(0.340/5/3) x86_64
        CMake:                       3.17.3
        CMake generator:             Ninja
        CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/ninja.exe
        Configuration:               RelWithDebInfo
    
      CPU/HW features:
        Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
          requested:                 SSE3
        Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
          requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
          SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
          SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
          FP16 (2 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
          AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
          AVX2 (8 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
          AVX512_SKX (0 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX
    
      C/C++:
        Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
        C++11:                       YES
        C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/g++.exe  (ver 10.2.0)
        C++ flags (Release):         -fpermissive   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
        C++ flags (Debug):           -fpermissive   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
        C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc.exe
        C flags (Release):           -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/opencv/v3.4/opencv-3.4.1-3.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/opencv-3.4.1-3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/opencv/v3.4/opencv-3.4.1-3.x86_64/src/opencv-3.4.1=/usr/src/debug/opencv-3.4.1-3   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
        C flags (Debug):             -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/opencv/v3.4/opencv-3.4.1-3.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/opencv-3.4.1-3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/opencv/v3.4/opencv-3.4.1-3.x86_64/src/opencv-3.4.1=/usr/src/debug/opencv-3.4.1-3   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
        Linker flags (Release):
        Linker flags (Debug):
        ccache:                      NO
        Precompiled headers:         NO
        Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
        3rdparty dependencies:
    
      OpenCV modules:
        To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching tracking ts video videoio videostab ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
        Disabled:                    dnn js world
        Disabled by dependency:      dnn_objdetect text
        Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv dnn_modern java matlab ovis sfm viz
        Applications:                tests apps
        Documentation:               NO
        Non-free algorithms:         NO
    
      GUI:
        GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.22.28)
          GThread :                  YES (ver 2.54.3)
          GtkGlExt:                  NO
        VTK support:                 NO
    
      Media I/O:
        ZLib:                        /lib/libz.dll.a (ver 1.2.11)
        JPEG:                        /lib/libjpeg.dll.a (ver )
        WEBP:                        /lib/libwebp.dll.a (ver encoder: 0x020e)
        PNG:                         /lib/libpng.dll.a (ver 1.6.37)
        TIFF:                        /lib/libtiff.dll.a (ver 42 / 4.2.0)
        JPEG 2000:                   /lib/libjasper.dll.a (ver 2.0.14)
        OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    
      Video I/O:
        GStreamer:
          base:                      YES (ver 1.12.5)
          video:                     YES (ver 1.12.5)
          app:                       YES (ver 1.12.5)
          riff:                      YES (ver 1.12.5)
          pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.12.5)
        gPhoto2:                     NO
    
      Parallel framework:            pthreads
    
      Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
    
      Other third-party libraries:
        Lapack:                      NO
        Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.9)
        Custom HAL:                  NO
        Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
    
      NVIDIA CUDA:                   NO
    
      OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
        Include path:                /usr/include/CL
        Link libraries:              Dynamic load
    
      Python 2:
        Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7.exe (ver 2.7.18)
        Libraries:                   /lib/libpython2.7.dll.a (ver 2.7.18)
        numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.16.2)
        packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
    
      Python 3:
        Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.7)
        Libraries:                   /lib/libpython3.8.dll.a (ver 3.8.7)
        numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.4)
        packages path:               lib/python3.8/site-packages
    
      Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7.exe
    
      Java:
        ant:                         NO
        JNI:                         NO
        Java wrappers:               NO
        Java tests:                  NO
    
      Matlab:                        NO
    
      Install to:                    /usr
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: it wont use, whatever ffmpeg you install. instead, make sure, `opencv_ffmpeg453_x64.dll`: (or whatever you have)  is on your PATH

Comment: sorry, `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg453_64.dll` , to be exact

Comment: `std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation();` and add the output to your post. since you said "cygwin", take advice with a grain of salt. I don't know of any builds of OpenCV for cygwin. there are official builds for Visual Studio/MSVC and someone's builds for mingw ("native" windows).

Comment: Using CYGWIN package unable to find "opencv_videoio_ffmpeg453_64.dll" for download. Am I missing something. Updated my post with getBuildInformation()